# Drop down menu aligned to left

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, menuitem

I was working on this [site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/) and added the header menu with drop downs. The third menu item **WINDOWS SUPPORT** sub menus are aligned to the left while others are aligned to to the center of the dropdown.I have edited the css to

```
.sub-menu li a {

text-align: center;
}
```

but the dropdown area is aligned to the right compared to others.Please help me in making it align correct.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked your site. just add these two classes in your css. it will resolve the problem.

```
#mainmenu .menu-item-292 ul
{
 left:-15px;
}

#mainmenu .menu-item-292 li
{
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

watch your css file and remove this 2 lines

```
#mainmenu .menu-item-291 a{margin-right:15px;}
#mainmenu .menu-item-292 a{margin-left:-16px;}
```

If you want to make more space use padding and border-box:box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
   #mainmenu .menu-item-292 a {
        margin-left: -16px;
    }
```

It's pulling over both the "Windows Support" anchor, and all anchors below it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Add **margin-left: 0;** css for given anchor tags into your style.css file I guess at line no. 383

```
#header #mainmenu ul.children li a, #header #mainmenu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'menu-font' !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem!